# Choco Can not delete output file : Access is denied

Tags: neovim, chocolatey

I'm running into an annoying error, My goal is to install the latest version of neovim(neovim version .5). I currently have neovim .4

1. I first uninstalled neovim by `choco uninstall neovim`
2. Then I ran `choco install neovim --pre` and got

```
ERROR: Can not delete output file : Access is denied. : C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin\lua51.dll
ERROR: Can not delete output file : Access is denied. : C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin\msgpackc.dll
ERROR: Can not delete output file : Access is denied. : C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin\nvim.exe
ERROR: Can not delete output file : Access is denied. : C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin\uv.dll
ERROR: Can not delete output file : Access is denied. : C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin\winpty.dll
ERROR: 7-Zip encountered a fatal error while extracting the files. This is most likely an issue with the 'neovim' package and not with Chocolatey itself. Please follow up with the package maintainer(s) directly.
The install of neovim was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\neovim\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - neovim (exited 2) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\neovim\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

The Log file mentioned in the error looks like this:

```
2021-06-16 23:53:13,553 4908 [DEBUG] - Moving 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\neovim'
 to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad\neovim'
2021-06-16 23:53:15,557 4908 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\Users\15732\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache\neovim.0.5.0-beta.nupkg".
2021-06-16 23:53:16,104 4908 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2021-06-16 23:53:16,104 4908 [INFO ] - 
2021-06-16 23:53:16,104 4908 [ERROR] - Failures
2021-06-16 23:53:16,104 4908 [ERROR] -  - neovim (exited 2) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\neovim\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
2021-06-16 23:53:16,104 4908 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2021-06-16 23:53:16,135 4908 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 2
```

Comment: open the image in a new tab so you don't leave this page

Comment: "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc." Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry, I'll fix it now

Comment: The output is directing you to look at `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log` for details. Please post that as well if you cannot solve your problem.

Comment: ok I am doing that know

Comment: Most of my problems with Chocolatey are solved by running and `choco` commands in a terminal ran as administrator

Comment: do you want all of the things inside the log file?

Comment: @Samathingamajig beat me to it! Most of my issues with Chocolatey are also resolved with a heightened shell (Run as administrator). Did you run the install in an administrator shell?

Comment: yes I ran the commands in (administrator) PowerShell

Comment: I shut down my computer and went to sleep, the next day I opened my computer and tried " choco install neovim  --pre " in (administrator) PowerShell, and now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

DLLs and exes are locked while you're running the application.
You were probably running Neovim and trying to upgrade it (I've just reproduced this error to confirm the output matched), which explains why it worked after rebooting your Windows.

If you have 'Access Denied' for .dll or .exe files be sure that you're not running the application that uses these files.

Also you probably had the same issue while trying to uninstall. You said you did uninstall, but one of the locked files from the error output was `C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin\nvim.exe`, so it was still present.